# Class design without using instanceof

Tags: java

I'm currently working on a class hierarchy. I have employees which can be engineers, salesmen and managers. They can all have managers but only a manager can be assigned as a manager. There is also an EmployeeAdmin class which basically holds the employees. I thought of setting this up using an interface since this does not involve strong coupling, or did I make a mistake here? The interface only defines the methods that are required in the EmployeeAdmin class.

```
ArrayList<IEmployee> employees = null;
```

For the class hierarchy I use an abstract base class since they all have methods which are required in all subclasses. The methods are: getId(), getManager(), setManager(...), payAmount(). The base class's name is Employee. I then derived some class's from this Employee class: Engineer, Salesman and Manager.

My problem is that I have no idea on how to set this up properly. From what I have seen, using interfaces ensures you are not having direct coupling. So anything that implements IEmployee can be an employee and added to the list. I don't know if this way of thinking is correct. Also, the setManager(...) method is causing me trouble, if I use IEmployee there I need to use instanceof to determine if it is a manager by using another interface or the class, right? On top of that, the EmployeeAdmin class also has a setManager(..., ...) method.

Is anyone willing to help me set this up properly and give his/her thoughts on this? I read that down-casting and instanceof are usually signs of bad/poor designs so I'm going to need some help.

EmployeeAdmin class:

```
public class EmployeeAdmin {
  private ArrayList<IEmployee> employees = null;
  public boolean setManager(IEmployee e, IEmployee m) {
    // Code to add manager to employee.
    e.setManager(m);
  }
}
```

By using interfaces, how would I set this up so that i can extract some employee from the list but also pas it in as for instance an IManager?

Comment: Why can't you make `setManager` accept a `Manager` as parameter? You obviously want this restriction, so why would you accept any other object types?

Comment: I could do that but then its directly coupled right? And what if I want to make a class CEO that can be a manager as well;

Comment: If `CEO` is a `Manager` then it obviously derives from it, so there's no issue here. And according to your design you want direct coupling for this case - it is not an inherently "bad" thing to have direct coupling, it should just be restricted to where it is necessary

Comment: According to my design I want direct coupling, why is that? How would I go about designing this so it is not directly coupled?

Comment: You could create a separate interface or abstract class for managers, but even then your `setManager` would be directly coupled to that. Again, it is not bad by default, as long as it is only used where necessary

Comment: I understand but I'm trying to find both ways to do it so that i can design it knowing how to do it in both ways. But using a separate interface, how would I go about doing that in the EmployeeAdmin class? There I have an ArrayList of IEmployee so then I would still need to use the instanceof?

Comment: Another way is that you don't use class hierarchy at all, instead set the employee type as an `enum` field and you evaluate the employee type based on this field.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza : Is using enums really a neat way of solving this?

Answer (score 3):

Since you said that only a manager can be accepted as a manager, then a solution is to have manager be its own interface and have the setManager method accept only managers. 
Consider the following base class:

```
public class Employee{
    private Manager manager;
    public final setManager(Manager manager){
        this.manager = manager;
    }
    public final Manager getManager(){
        return manager;
    }
    //... other methods and logic common to all employees
 }
```

Now define the manager interface:

```
public interface Manager{
    public void registerEmployeeAsSubordinate(Employee employee);
    public void someOtherMethodCommonToAllManagers();
}
```

Now lets have a Regional Manager implementation:

```
public class RegionalManager extends Employee implements Manager{
    private void ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
    public void someRegionalManagerMethod(){
         //... this logic belongs to this specific manager
    }
    @Override
    public void registerEmployeeAsSubordinate(Employee employee){
        employees.add(employee);
    }
    @Override
    public void someMethodCommonToAllManagers(){
         //... some logic
    }
}
```

Now, for a CEO

```
public class CEO extends Employee implements Manager{
    private void ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
    public void someCEOMethod(){
         //... this logic belongs to this specific manager
    }
    @Override
    public void registerEmployeeAsSubordinate(Employee employee){
        employees.add(employee);
    }
    @Override
    public void someMethodCommonToAllManagers(){
         //... some logic
    }
}
```

And an engineer:

```
public class Engineer extends Employee{
    public void someEngineerMethod(){
        //...
    }
}
```

All managerial or employees implementations are decoupled, if you change the logic on `CEO`, you won't need to recompile any other class but itself. Same for `RegionalManager`

In this example if you attempt to use a non Manager class in `setManager` the code won't even compile as it expects a Manager to be provided.

So you see, your instinct on using interfaces is correct, hope the example helps.

Edit:
Now, for your specific Implementation, you are actually going the opposite way, when you accept an interface implementation for employee, you are coupling your code to that `IEmployee` contract. What you migth want to do is:

```
 public class EmployeeAdmin {
  private ArrayList<Employee> employees;
  public boolean setManager(Employee e, Manager m) {
    // Code to add manager to employee.
    e.setManager(m);
  }
 }
```

This way you don't have to check for which kind of employee interface you're using, if you have to check for it, then you are likely not taking full advantage of polymorphism.

Additional Edit: You might want to read about `Liskov Substitution` for getting the most of your subclasses. Its a bit hard to grasp at first, but good sub-classing will help you out tons when programming to interfaces instead of implementations. `Head First Design Patterns` is a great and friendly approach to good coding principles, but if you're hardcore go straight to `Clean Code` by Robert "Uncle Bob" Martin.

Liskov substitution basically means that you must be able to talk to a sub class just as you would talk to its super class, that is what efficient subclassing is all about. If at some point you need to talk to a subclass in a way that the super class would not understand or cause an error (i.e. needing to use instanceof ) then what you need is a different class, not a subclass.

Try to find ways to use inheritance and polymorphism instead, say for example, in your base class you can have a method called `performMainJob()` and using polymorphism, you would define that to be a call to a method `solveProblem()` for an Engineer subclass and a call to a method `verifyBooks()` for an Accountant subclass.

This way, you will be able to just call `employee.performMainJob()` and have it polymorphically dispatched without worrying about the specific subclass implementation. That's how you know you have a Liskov substitution compliant subclass, talking to `Engineer` or `Accountant` is the same as talking to its superclass `Employee` they can be a substitute for one another.

Polymorphism should be enough to deploy decoupled subclasses, if you need more flexibility than that, take a look at the `Strategy Pattern` to be able to use objects to implement different and more flexible behaviours. Again, Head First Design Patterns from O'Reilly is an invaluable and friendly resource, give it a try.

Comment: First, thank you for your answer. I understand what you are doing here. However, in my case there is no ArrayList in Manager but there is another class which contains the ArrayList. That class also has a method setManager. So, the engineer, salesman and manager are in that ArrayList. My question now then is, how would i set this up properly so that the setManager method in this class, EmployeeAdmin, accepts classes/interfaces and so that I don't have to use the instanceof and/or down-casting or is this not the correct way of doiong it? I altered my question so the class definition is shown.

Comment: The `ArrayList` is only for the sake of the example just a taste of a possible implementation (you may want to consider something like that for the sake of encapsulation). In this case, in this example there's no use of `instanceof` in employee, no need for it or for any kind of extra casting, thats why the interface is useful.

Comment: I understand but in our case we have an ArrayList containing Engineera, Salesmen AND managers. So how would I then go about using a setManager method that can extract it from the ArrayList based on the id but alao has to be a manager? If you know what I mean? I'm thinking: setManager(IEmployee e, IManager m)

Comment: I understand now, its not "wrong" but, if you use the interface instead of the base class you are actually coupling your code to the specific interface.  If you need to do that, then is possible that you are not subclassing as efficiently as you can.

Comment: Not subclassing as efficiently as possible? How would you suggest to do this? Well, you are always coupling to something right? Interfaces are better then direct classes or am i wrong about this?

Comment: Liskov substitution basically means that you must be able to talk to a sub class just as you would talk to its super class, that is what efficient subclassing is all about.

Answer (score 0):

General comment first, be cautious not to over-abstract your code just because you heard there should not be tight coupling.

By correct application of OOP principles, a Manager is *not* an interface. A Manager is a type of Employee.

You are on the right track with the interface. But to be true to the original design intent of interfaces, the interface you want is not quite "Employee", it is *Employable*.

"Any Employee is Employable".

The abstract class you want (for common behavior that applies to all Employees) is Employee, and to enforce the required behaviors of anything Employable at your company, it implements the Employable interface. Perhaps in the future a Contractor could implement the Employable interface too. See? It's not a full-time employee, but it must provide certain obligations to be Employable.

Anyway, the Manager, Salesman, and Engineer classes all Extend the Employee class. They are all a Type Of Employee.

To handle the requirement that employees have managers, for example, the Salesman and Engineer would contain a private Manager property/variable (with a get set, or perhaps just set in the constructor), specifying who their manager is. For the Manager, you could allow this to be optional, if not all Managers have a Manager of their own.

And so on.

Comment: I heard that before but I would like to understand on how to do this. My question still remains on how this should be implemented so that the EmployeeAdmin can use this setManager method as well. I altered the question so that this is shown. In this case would you say that IEmployable can then have the function definitions of getId() etc.?

Comment: Sorry, was on vacation. Yes that is on the right track. Anyone who is Employable would be required to produce their employee id when asked, so IEmployable would require anything fulfilling that contract to implement a getId().

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new interface **IManager** which extends **IEmployee**. This will help in accommodating manager in *employees* list.
**IEmployee.java**

```
public interface IEmployee {
  //other methods
  public void setManager(IManager mgr);
}
```

**IManager.java**

```
public interface IManager extends IEmployee {
   //Manager specific methods
}
```

**Employee.java**

```
public abstract Employee implements IEmployee  {
}
```

**Manager.java**

```
public abstract Manager extends Employee implements IManager{
}
```

EmployeeAdmin.java

```
public class EmployeeAdmin {
  private ArrayList<IEmployee> employees = null;
  public boolean setManager(IEmployee e, IManager m) {
    // Code to add manager to employee.
    e.setManager(m);
  }
}
```

**CEO.java**

```
public class CEO extends Manager {
}
```

**Engineer.java**

```
public class Engineer extends Employee {
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, then how would I go from an IEmployee to an IManager? If for instance the setManager(int e, int m)   has this defitinion in EmployeeAdmin

Comment: I am not following the example setManager(int e, int m). It will be setManager(IEmployee e, IManager m), right.

Comment: Well, thats how it was build now. But if i use your function definition then i would need casting right? Because the ArrayList contains only IEmployee so I would need to use intsanceof and cast it to IManager?

Comment: Agreed you need to down cast. To avoid this you can add set of IManager in EmployeeAdmin. This set will contain reference to IManager which is added in employees list as IEmployee. So for a reference of IEmployee if manager is present in the set it can be used without down casting.